# Show that the ring is unital? (Abstract algebra)

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

HERE IS THE QUESTION:

For $a/b$ and $c/d$ rational numbers, say $\frac ab ≡ \frac cd \pmod 1$ if $\frac ab − \frac cd$ is an integer. Call the set of congruence classes mod 1, $\Bbb Q/\Bbb Z$.
 Define addition and multiplication in $\Bbb Q/\Bbb Z$ by working with representatives
between $0$ and $1$ as follows.
 If $0 < \frac ab < 1$ and $0 < \frac cd < 1$ then $\frac ab · \frac cd = \frac {ac}{bd}$ and
 $\frac ab + \frac cd =$ the fractional part of $\frac{ab+cd}{bd}$

MY PROBLEM:

SO I am really confused about what the unit in such a ring would be. Since $\frac ab$ and $\frac bc$ are both between $0$ and $1$, it is impossible to multiply any element with another element and get $1$ because when you multiply to numbers between $0$ and $1$ with each other, you end up with a number between $0$ and $1$. So I feel like this ring does not have a unit!!

Please help!

Comment: Are you sure about the addition? (My counterexample works with this as well as the addition I would have expected)

Comment: Your question does not state what happens when one of the rational representatives is $0$ or $1$. Also, your "HERE IS THE QUESTION" section does not actually include any question, which strikes me as suspicious. Does this come from some source?

Comment: If addition is closed, $\frac 12+\frac12=\frac01$ is in your set, but then you haven't defined multiplication with it...

Answer (score 2):

You are right, this ring has no unit. It is not even a nonunital ring because
$$([\tfrac12]+[\tfrac12])[\tfrac12]=[0]\ne[\tfrac12]= [\tfrac12][\tfrac12]+[\tfrac12][\tfrac12]$$

Comment: It has to be unital because the question is asking me to prove that it is unital. I feel it has something to do with a/b = c/d (mod 1) is (a/b - c/d) is an integer

Comment: @anon Thanks, although I'm not sure why retyping the equation appearing above was supposed to be helpful. Retrying the computation without 5:30 a.m. brain got me the right answer.

Answer (score 1):

<s>This multiplication operation is not well defined: if it were, then $\frac 12=\frac 11\frac 12=\frac 01\frac 12=\frac 02$ , which is absurd.</s>

This addition operation is not well defined either: $\frac12=\frac32=\frac 11+\frac 12=\frac01+\frac12=\frac22=\frac02$.

So, there is evidentially an integrity problem in your source or your transcription.

Withdrawn until user explains (or fails to explain) how one is to multiply with $\frac01$ (the closure of addition necessitates that this is in the set.)

Comment: Technically, the stipulations leave the multiplication undefined when one of the numbers is $0$ or $1$.

Comment: @anon Ah, that exclusion slipped by me. Thanks